# Bzr Explorer used for Git repositories

Tags: git, version-control, bazaar-plugins

I have been using Bazaar as version control system since many years and I am evaluating a migration to Git.

The issue that keeps me off has nothing to do with git itself but with its GUI: Bzr Explorer has many features that lack in Git GUI counterparts.

I've read that Bzr Explorer can be used on a Git repository by simply installing the package bzr-git.

After installing that package (on Linux Ubuntu 18.04), Bzr Explorer can explore Git repositories, but with following limitations:

1. The working tree on the right isn't displayed at all.
2. Files added or modified, pending to be committed, are shown but their differences can't be seen.
3. Commits can't be applied ( because no difference are seen  )

In a few words, it is only possible to see the repository history, but no action on the working tree is allowed ( diff, add, commit )

My questions are the following:

1. Should I have to configure something else for Bzr Explorer to work properly ?
2. Is there a similar GUI for Git ? I know this may be a duplicate question, but the original question has many years and perhaps a new GUI for Git is available.

Answer (score 1):

[GitGui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) (I mean the latest 2.27) should be close to [Bzr Explorer](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/explorer/en/)

But in case it is not, try [gitahead](https://gitahead.github.io/gitahead.com/) ([GitHub project](https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead)), which is quite complete as well.

[GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) remains the best, but... the [free version](https://www.gitkraken.com/pricing?product=git-gui) might not be feature complete enough for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tested GitGui as well as gitk, gitg and qgit, and although they are good GUI for Git, they are not so good as Bzr Explorer (IMHO). Also, I'm searching for a free open source project, included as a package in Debian / Ubuntu distro or a way to use Bzr Explorer with a Git repository without the errors I have pointed out . Nevertheless I'll give a try to gitahead.

Comment: @RomualdoCaruso You can see it installed here (https://gist.github.com/thiagomgo/077aef9abdd5fd72299872e6a92c5f9a#file-post-install-mint-ubuntu-sh-L168-L176), using https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/releases/download/v2.6.2/GitAhead-2.6.2.sh